# Scala bufferedinput stream reader

Tags: scala, bufferedreader

I have a scala program as below

```
object TestApp {
  def main(args: Array[String]): Unit = {
    val in = new BufferedInputStream(new FileInputStream("testBytes.txt"))
    val buffer = Array.ofDim[Byte](15)
    while (in.read(buffer)>0) {
      println(new String(buffer))
    }
  }
}
```

The input file contains "AAAAAAAAAABBBBBBBBBB"

When I run this program I'm getting the below results

```
AAAAAAAAAABBBBB
BBBBBAAAAABBBBB
```

I'm confused why the buffer keeps old read data still, Or any way to avoid this?

I'm expecting something like this

```
AAAAAAAAAABBBBB
BBBBB
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `read` method returns the number of bytes read. Only use these bytes in the buffer. E.g.

```
var len = 0
while ({len = in.read(buffer); len} > 0) {
  println(new String(buffer, 0, len))
}
```

Comment: It's actually `public int read(byte[] b`, defined under `java.io.InputStream`. See documentation at http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/index.html